# Is it possible to perform one `get` and two `insert`s on a HashMap with only one lookup?

Tags: rust, hashmap

I have an application where I need to:

1. Lookup a value in a hash table and return it if it exists
2. If it didn't exist, store a temp value
3. Compute a new value using the other values in the table
4. Store the new value into the hash table
5. Return the new value

I'd like to do this with only 1 hash/lookup.  Is that possible?  Is it possible to do it with 2?

---

I'm computing Fibonacci to show the purpose. The function that would be nice to optimize from 3 lookups to 1 lookup is the `index()` function:

```
// Written by beefucurry

use std::collections::HashMap;

use std::cell::UnsafeCell;

fn main() {
    let fib = SaveCall::<u32, u32>::new(|k, fib_| {
        if k < 2 {
            return k;
        } else {
            return fib_[k - 1] + fib_[k - 2];
        }
    });

    for k in (0..30).rev() {
        println!("fib[{}] = {}", k, fib[k]);
    }
}

pub struct SaveCall<'a, In: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash + Copy, Out> {
    cache: UnsafeCell<HashMap<In, Option<Out>>>,
    f: Box<dyn Fn(In, &SaveCall<'a, In, Out>) -> Out + 'a>,
}
impl<'a, In: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash + Copy, Out> SaveCall<'a, In, Out> {
    pub fn new(f: impl Fn(In, &Self) -> Out + 'a) -> Self {
        Self {
            cache: UnsafeCell::new(HashMap::new()),
            f: Box::new(f),
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, In: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash + Copy, Out> std::ops::Index<In>
    for SaveCall<'a, In, Out>
{
    type Output = Out;
    fn index<'b>(&'b self, input: In) -> &'b Self::Output {
        unsafe {
            //println!("~~Looking up {:?}", input);
            let cache = self.cache.get();
            let saved = (*cache).get(&input);
            if saved.is_some() {
                //println!("~~Found {:?}", input);
                let z = saved.unwrap().as_ref();
                if z.is_some() {
                    return z.unwrap();
                } else {
                    panic!("Attempted to compute a value based on itself");
                }
            }
            (*cache).insert(input, None);
            //println!("~~Computing {:?}", input);
            let output: Out = (self.f)(input, self);
            //println!("~~Writing to cache {:?}", input);
            (*cache).insert(input, Some(output));
            let output_ref = (*cache).get(&input).unwrap().as_ref().unwrap();
            output_ref
        }
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5dc26bdd4273d7d897e61ab0d9909aa5)

Comment: What is the point of step 2 in this process? Is it necessary?

Comment: It isn't totally necessary, but since the computation will itself look at the hashtable, a temp value allows me check that I'm not trying to read that value while computing it.

Comment: 6. ??? 7. profit. no seriously what you want don't make sense please give an example some code that show what you want !

Comment: Ah okay. If your computation has to look at the table, but I don't think this is possible as-is. You can absolutely look up a key, and create it if it isn't found, but only if Rust can guarantee that the table hasn't changed, which it can't do if you need to access the table during computation.

Comment: FYI, just looking at your code now. Your code is unsound and could crash. I don't believe it is possible to use the index trait for what you want to do, because the index trait requires a reference into your hashmap, but you want to simultaneously mutate the hashmap as items are indexed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd like to do this with only 1 hash/lookup. Is that possible?

It is not possible with a single hash lookup because Rust has no way to know whether the calculation itself might try to change the structure of your `SaveCall` object. If your callback didn't accept `self` as a parameter, then it would be possible, but not with the API as you want it.

> Is it possible to do it with 2?

It is possible with 2 using [`HashMap::entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry), which lets you search for a key in the map, and modify the location and inspect whether or not it had a value, without having to recompute the hash.

You can use this to compute the hash once when you initially query the table and either return or insert `None`, and then you can insert normally when you have the final result.

This takes us to your code itself. It is not possible to use the `std::ops::Index` trait to do what you want. Your example code has tried to get around this with `UnsafeCell`, but your unsafe code violates the requirements that unsafe code must adhere to.

The short version is that the `Index` trait returns a reference. You specifically want to mutate the map by inserting entries as you access them, that means that the HashMap must grow and reallocate space for its values as it does so. If you have to re-allocate, it means that there is no way for the references returned by the `index` to remain valid, since they were referencing to the memory that was re-allocated.

Where does that leave you?

1. You need to stop using the `Index` trait, and instead implement a method on your `SavedCall` type that does not return a reference.
2. You need to decide what you want to return instead. If you want to return `Out` directly, then `Out` needs to explicitly be a `Copy` type. If you want to support non-Copy types, then you'd potentially need to return an `Rc` or an `Arc`.

For example

```
impl<'a, In: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash + Copy, Out> SaveCall<'a, In, Out> {
    fn get(&self, input: In) -> Rc<Out> {
```

or

```
impl<'a, In: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash + Copy, Out: Copy> SaveCall<'a, In, Out> {
    fn get(&self, input: In) -> Out {
```

Here's a more complete version built on your example code [on the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dd13e63c491600d5c1a0d33b38261fc7). This uses Rc to best demonstrate the example, but you can trim it down if `Out: Copy` is fine.

Comment: Ack, I should have realized Rust Hashmap doesn't guarantee data doesn't move, I even watched a C++ lecture where they mentioned that.  I think I'm going to use Out : copy.  I only used a &Out because the index trait forced that.  I'm going to think about converting my input to requiring Into<usize> and store things in a Box<> instead, so I don't have so much overhead.  Thanks a ton.